# Swift 2.0 - NSMutableArray - Remove Object

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nsmutablearray

In my code I created a loop where it creates `UIView`s and `UIButton`s depending how many objects are in the array.

Everything works as it should be and every time I press a delete button a `UIView` is removed from the superview.

However, if I press the first time the Delete Button in the top `UIView` with `tag=0`, the function `loadUser` is repeated 3 times crashing the app.

What I am doing wrong in my code?

```
var customViewUser: UIView?
var names:NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    userNames()
    LoadUsers()
}

func userNames(){
    names = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff"]
}

func LoadUsers() {
    let countUsers = names.count

    print("\(countUsers) Users")
    for (index, _) in names.enumerate() {
        print("User n: \(index)")

        let userNameViewsY = CGFloat(index * 128)

        //FIRST USER VIEW
        customViewUser = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, userNameViewsY, self.view.frame.size.width, 128))
        customViewUser!.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
        customViewUser!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        customViewUser!.layer.borderWidth = 3
        customViewUser!.tag = index
        self.view.addSubview(customViewUser!)

        let customButtonDeleteVideoUser = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(customViewUser!.frame.size.width - 200, 4, 100, 28))
        customButtonDeleteVideoUser.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        customButtonDeleteVideoUser.setTitle("Delete", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        customButtonDeleteVideoUser.addTarget(self, action: "deleteButton:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
        customViewUser!.addSubview(customButtonDeleteVideoUser)
        // set tag
        customButtonDeleteVideoUser.tag = index
    }
}

func deleteButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let index = sender.tag

    print(" User \(index) selected")
    let CustomSubViews = self.view.subviews

    for subview in CustomSubViews {
        if subview.tag == index {
            print(subview.tag)

            if index >= 0  {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()

                names.removeObjectAtIndex(index)

                print(names)
                LoadUsers()
            }
        }

        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: How many buttons do you see on your UI? Are they of same number as that of views? Also, try adding different actions for each button.

Comment: I can 6 six UIView and 6 UIButton right now

Comment: Shorten your array to contain only 2 strings and in your `LoadUsers ` use different action methods based on the index. For instance `deleteButton1:` for first and `deleteButton2:` for second. Try this out.

Comment: This would work however, the array is generated from a file and never know how many objects it can contain

Answer (score 1):

All subviews to which you did not set a tag, will have a tag of 0.

So here your code is finding other subviews with tag value 0:

```
for subview in CustomSubViews {
            if subview.tag == index {
```

Just use tags starting with 1 and you should be ok:

```
customButtonDeleteVideoUser.tag = index + 1
```

and

```
let index = sender.tag - 1
```

and

```
        if subview.tag == index+1 {
```

This solves the problem, and the function will be called only once. But you will have other problems:

- when removing various views, the array will become shorter and you will have tags without corresponding array positions:                     names.removeObjectAtIndex(index) will crash if you don't update the tags
- also it seems that when you delete one view you add a few more, not sure if this is intentional.

Comment: thank you.. I have tried that however, the function is still returned 3 times if I press on the first delete button

Comment: So it is now finding 3 views with tag == 1? That's strange, is there any other code where you set tags? Try to use the debugger to identify what views it is finding.

Comment: No other views are in the project. Its a very simple test and it crashes I i push the first delete button. Here the project if you fancy have at look. http://we.tl/bDZfIjYW4O

Comment: I checked and edited my answer, you have to change 3 lines instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS7, `UIViewController` supplies and maintains two invisible views, the **top layout guide** and the **bottom layout guide**, which it injects as subviews into the view hierarchy of its main view. So when you call

```
let CustomSubViews = self.view.subviews
```

You're accidentally getting those invisible views as well (you can see for yourself in debugger), and by default their `tag == 0`, that's why the code in your `if subview.tag == index` statement will run 3 times when `tag == 0` (once for your view, and the other 2 for those invisible views).

- I would not recommend relying on the fact that all the subviews were created by you
- using `tag == 0` for view identification is really bad idea, since all views have this value by default...

Anyway, the easiest fix to your current code would be to add condition to the mentioned above `if` statement:

```
// The invisible views are of type `_UILayoutGuide*`
if subview.tag == index && subview.isMemberOfClass(UIView.self)
```